# Nested virtualization on GCP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, google-compute-engine

i have enabled the nested virtualization on a GCP VM instance running Ubuntu. it was working perfectly. from last few days this vm was power off and today when powered it on nested virtualization was disabled?

any idea why its disabled now and how i can enable it again?

root@ubuntu:~# grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo
0
root@ubuntu:~# init 0

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, when you reboot the instance the nested virtualisation keeps working.

It's when you stop and restart the instance, that the nested virtualization is no longer operative.

In that case the command `grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo`  returns a 0.

This behavior is a known bug on Google Cloud Platform. It is about to be resolved, even though but there is no ETA yet.

Please consult this public issue [link](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/74331427).

Comment: The link to be consulted is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74331427